# Question on countable sets

Tags: real-analysis

A countable set contained in $[0,1]$ with no limit points. The question asks if such a request is possible. I think it is. Consider $\{1/n\}$. This is a countable set and it's a subset of $[0,1]$. If I wanted a countable set in [0,1] with no isolated points, this would be impossible I believe.

Comment: If by $\{1/n\}$ you mean the set of all numbers $1/n,$ where $n$ is a positive integer, then you are wrong because this set has a limit point in $[0,1],$ which is $0$

Comment: I just realized this! I need to rethink I guess.

Comment: Note that $[0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ (and hence it contains all of its limit points).

Comment: So it contains all of its limit points. So any set (countable or not) that is contained in $[0,1]$ must have limit points?

Comment: No, it means that if you take a set $A\subseteq[0,1]$ then the set $A'$ of all limit points of $A$ is a subset of $[0,1]$ (it is possible that $A'=\varnothing$ for some $A\subseteq[0,1],$ for example $\{0\}$)

Comment: A finite set is countable, but I assume you mean "countably infinite".

Comment: So if we have a subset $A$ of $[0,1]$, then $A'$ is a subset of $[0,1]$. I'm not understanding the motivation here.

Comment: Countable meaning we can find a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [0,1]$.

Comment: @NickR That actually depends on the author (despite the fact that it's easier to count a finite set than an infinite one, so they should be "even more countable," right?). Some authors use "countable" to mean countably infinite, and use "at most countable" to mean what you mean by countable.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus I guess I was looking for some wiggle room to provide a positive answer.  It is clearly not possible as countably infinite.

Comment: @Moz An example of a set that doesn't contain its limit points is $(0,1)$, by the way.

Comment: @NickR I'm not sure if "clearly" is the right word. It's not true for $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ (seen as a subset of $\Bbb Q$), for example, which makes it seem like the fact that it works when $\Bbb Q$ is replaced by $\Bbb R$ wouldn't be clear to someone who hadn't seen the proof before. (Though, I agree, it is not possible for a countably infinite set.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus Good point.  "Clear" is not the best choice of words.  The subtleties of set theory are a minefield, and my modest understanding has often exploded in my face.

Comment: Is a countable set in $[0,1]$ with no isolated points impossible, since we would require an infinitely many terms in the set so that there are no isolated points?

Comment: @Moz The countable set $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ has no isolated points and is a subset of $[0,1]$. Did you mean to say "limit points"?

Comment: I did mean isolated points. There is a third part to the problem which asks if "A set with an uncountable number of isolated points" is possible and I thought this was true and so by elimination the isolated points problem was false.

Comment: Can you explain why $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ has no isolated points? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to review the definitions of the terms…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, countable set of points in $[0,1]$ must have a limit point.

Answer (score 2):

Mimic the proof of the
Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Divide the segment into two parts.
One of them must have
an infinite number of points.

Divide that segment into two parts.
One of those must have an infinite number of points.

Keep on doing this,
each time keeping the segment
with an infinite number of points.

After $n$ times,
there is a segment
of length $1/2^n$
with an infinite number of points.

The limit of this segment
is a point in the set which is 
a limit of points in the set.

Comment: Mimic _a_ proof of the theorem.

Comment: Mimic the proof of a theorem.

Comment: Mimic the man sitting next to you until he feels sufficiently creeped out. Then run.

Comment: For a good time, visit math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'll appeal to the fact that $[0,1]$ is *compact;* that is, every open cover has a finite subcover.

Consider the open cover
$$U=\{G:G\text{ is an open set$\\$containing at most one$\\$point of }A\}$$
If $U$ covers $[0,1]$, then it has a finite subcover $U'$, each containing at most one point of $A$. This would imply that $A$ is finite, contradicting the hypothesis that $A$ is infinite.

Can you show that $U$ covers $[0,1]$, if $A$ has no limit point? *(Hint: if $A$ equals $\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots\}$ — which* does *have a limit point — then no set in $U$ would contain $0$, and $U$ wouldn't cover $[0,1]$.)*